# How to freeze Secondary Tiles WP8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, secondary-live-tile

I'm trying to create a secondary tile, but I only want the stuff on the back of the tile to be shown. Is this possible when targeting WP8.0 devices?

```
    private void MenuItem0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StandardTileData standardTileData = new StandardTileData();
        standardTileData.BackTitle = "AppTitle0";
        standardTileData.BackContent = "AppTitle1";
        standardTileData.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/red_background.png", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using StandardTileData use IconicTileData. This has only one(front) side to the tile.

```
//Creating a iconic tile class 
IconicTileData iconic = new IconicTileData() 
{ 
    Title = "iconic tile", 
    Count = 87, 
    WideContent1 = "Battery left 87%", 
    WideContent2 = "estimated time remainning", 
    WideContent3 = "21 hours 24 min", 
    SmallIconImage = new Uri("Images/Iconic.png", UriKind.Relative), 
    IconImage = new Uri("Images/Iconic.png", UriKind.Relative), 
}; 

//Always provide a unique tile navigation uri to the each secondary tile that is pinned through the application 
string tileuri = string.Concat("/MainPage.xaml?", "id=iconic"); 

if (tile == null) 
{ 
    //Creating a new secondary flip tile on start screen having the properties as provided by the Tiledata class 
    //and the navigation uri given by tileuri string member 
    ShellTile.Create(new Uri(tileuri, UriKind.Relative), iconic,true); 
}
```

This is how to create a Iconic tile.

Comment: I don't want to use a wide tile to show my information. I want to use a medium size tile.